# why error msProcessProjection(): Projection library error?

Tags: mapserver, proj, epsg, mapfile

I'm using mapserver in Centos 7. I'm using fgs from this  (http://www.maptools.org/fgs/index.phtml?page=downloads.html). I'm using mapfile with epsg:4326, but I get error

`<ServiceException> msProcessProjection(): Projection library error. no options found in 'init' file msProcessProjection(): Projection library error. no options found in 'init' file </ServiceException>`

this is my mapfile

```
LAYER
    METADATA
        "DESCRIPTION" "Border"
        "wms_title"   "Border"
        "wms_enable_request" "*"
        "ows_name"    "Border"
        "ows_srs"     "epsg:4326"
        "gml_include_items" "all"
        "gml_featureid"     "gid"
        "ows_enable_request" "*"
    END
    
    PROJECTION
        'init=epsg:4326'
    END

    # TRANSPARENCY 50

    NAME "border"
    CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
    CONNECTION "user=# dbname=# host=# port=# password=#"
    DATA "geom FROM (SELECT st_geomfromtext(geom) as geom, gid FROM map_border) tmp using unique gid using srid=4326"
    TYPE POLYGON
    STATUS ON

    CLASS
        NAME "Border"
        STYLE
            COLOR 128 0 0
            OUTLINECOLOR 255 0 0
            OPACITY 30
            LINECAP BUTT 
            WIDTH 2 
            PATTERN 1 4 END
        END
    END

    PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER"

END
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

MapServer is using the Proj library for coordinate transformations. Now your MapServer does not find the library and therefore it cannot resolve what `init=epsg:4326` means. If your system does not know where to find PROJ_LIB then one alternative is to tell that in the mapfile https://mapserver.org/mapfile/map.html. Notice that the paths below are examples, you must use a path that is correct for your own system.

> PROJ_LIB [path]
>
> This CONFIG parameter can be used to define the location of your EPSG
> files for the PROJ library. Setting the [key] to PROJ_LIB and the
> [value] to the location of your EPSG files will force PROJ to use this
> value. Using CONFIG allows you to avoid setting environment variables
> to point to your PROJ_LIB directory. Here are some examples:
>
> Unix
>
> ```
> CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "/usr/local/share/proj/"
> ```
>
> Windows
>
> ```
> CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "C:/somedir/proj/nad/"
> ```

Answer (score 1):

FGS is not maintained & has not seen any improvements since about 13 years now, and that page should most likely be removed (it contains an insecure version of MapServer, Apache, etc.).  FGS is absolutely not recommended today (I can say this because I was also involved with its development back then).   You should review the other options for binaries at https://mapserver.org/download.html#binaries or invest some time & effort to compile MapServer yourself : follow https://mapserver.org/installation/unix.html